# "missing autoprint content" error in PythonTeX

Tags: python

I just installed PythonTeX in MiKTeX/windows, with latest python 2.7. The installation looks fine to me. I got all the files in MiKTeX directory and the `pythontex.bat` file in `miktex/bin`. Then I try to run a simple code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\begin{document}
\py{2+3}
\end{document}
```

I run TeX first, then `pythontex.py` file in the MiKTeX folder and run MiKTeX again. Both time I got the warning: Missing autoprint content. And the .pdf shows "??". I am not sure what's the problem here. Seems to me that python didn't execute the code. The first several lines of the `.pytxcode` is:

```
=>PYTHONTEX#py#default#default#0#i#####6#
2+3
=>PYTHONTEX:SETTINGS#
version=0.14
outputdir=pythontex-files-test
workingdir=.
workingdirset=false
gobble=none
```

I am new to both LaTeX and python. Can anyone help me with this problem.

Comment: This works fine for me when using `pdflatex test.tex`, then `pythontex test.tex`, then `pdflatex test.tex`. You might make sure that the PDF is being refreshed after the second compile; I've seen a case where there was a delay for some reason. If that isn't it, can you delete the output folder `pythontex-files-test`, run `pythontex` again, and post the output message?  Also, what commands are you using for the LaTeX compiling?

Comment: Hi Geoffrey! Thank you for your help. I think I may have some basic problems here. First I didn't use cmd to compile LaTeX before. I simply just click the run bottom in MiKTeX (maybe right) and double click the pythontex (this maybe seriously wrong). Now I put the pythontex.bat file in the same folder as the test.tex file and use the cmd: `pdflatex test.tex` then `pythontex test.tex`. Here I got an error: `ImportError: No module named pygments.styles`.

Comment: Now I think about it, the problem should be in python. I am using a separate python distribution Anaconda. When I installed pygments, it was installed under the folder of Anaconda, not in the original Python folder. Maybe that's why pythontex cannot find the pygments module? Is there a way to direct pythontex where to search for modules? Thank you!

Comment: Having the .bat file in `miktex/bin` is what you want, since that should be on your PATH (although if the .bat file specifies the full path, it will work elsewhere). If you are only using Anaconda Python, you might uninstall the other version. Otherwise, you could install Pygments for the other version. Or you could edit the .bat file to specify the version of Python that should be used. Using the run button in your editor for running LaTeX should be fine.

Comment: Unfortunately there is a new error now. When I run `pythontex test.tex`, cmd shows error: `usage: pythontex.py [-h] [--version] [--encoding ENCODING][--error-exit-code <true,false>][--runall [<true,false>]|--rerun<never,modified,errors,warnings,always>][--hashdependencies [<true,false>]][-j N][-v][--interpreter INTERPRETER][--debug[<family>:<session>:<restart>]|--interactive[<family>:<session>:<restart>]] TEXNAME pythontex.py: error: too few arguments` Sorry I have no idea what does it mean and how should I solve it.

Comment: And another problem is I don't have a pythontex-files-test folder. When I run the last `pdflatex test.tex`, it shows: `No file pythontex-files-test/test.pytxmcr`. I know that should be the out put folder as you mentioned. But I don't know why I couldn't create it.

Comment: How did you install? Did you use the installation script? Or manually copy files?

Comment: I use cmd (under admin) to run `pythontex_install.bat`, then chose the MiKTex folder to install the package. When the installation is finished, I run `initexmf --admin --update-fndb`. All the files that mentioned in the documentation are in the correct position under Miktex.

Comment: There won't be a folder unless `pythontex` can run successfully once. So you can ignore that suggestion. If things are installed correctly, I don't know why `pythontex test.tex` would cause errors. If running `pythontex --version` works, and you are in the same directory as `test.tex`, everything should be fine.

Comment: If I run `pythontex --version`, it will give the same error: `too few arguments`.I try to re-install anaconda and pythontex but it still doesn't work. From python it looks like this error is from `_parse_known_args` `self.error(_('too few arguments'))`. I am not sure what happened here. Maybe I will try not to use anaconda and try it. Thank you.

Comment: I uninstalled anaconda and use simple python2.7. Everything looks fine now. I am not entirely sure if anaconda is the cause of the problem here. I will just live with this solution for now.

Comment: My guess is that you had a configuration issue with Anaconda.  You probably needed to set `assoc` and `ftype`.  See [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#executing-scripts) for how to do this.  You would just change their example to use Anaconda instead.